# Writing a function to separate working vs. error values in R

Tags: r, function, try-catch

I've been using this awesome code from the Heuristic Andrew [blog](http://heuristically.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/geolocate-ip-addresses-in-r/)

where you can geolocate IP addresses. I want to be able to run the function over a large (24867 IPs) vector of IP addresses. The problem is most of the IP addresses will return the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") : cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

I'm assuming this occurs because the IP address can not be traced.

I want to create a subset of the vector of IP addresses that will give me the location. I think I would need to write another function puts the IP address into a new vector of working IP addresses, or into a different vector of error IP addresses.

I think I would also need to use the `try` or `tryCatch` function?

I'm new to programming so I don't know how to write a function. I've looked at examples online but can't quite figure it out. Any advice would be appreciated.

***EDIT:***
Thanks to @Thomas for pointing me down the right road...

I used the function is.error to determine if `try()` will give me an error or not. Returns a logical vector:

```
is.error <- function(x) inherits(x, "try-error")
```

Tried using `lapply()`

```
> is.error(
+   try(
+     lapply(X  = ls_IPaddresses, FUN = freegeoip)
+     )
+   )
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
[1] TRUE
```

The length of ls_IPaddresses is 24867, so I would want a logical vector with the same length so I can subset the logical vector against ls_IPaddresses.

Comment: `try` should be sufficient here (basically just wrap the `readLines` function in `try` and return `NULL` when `inherits(x, "try-error")`). Take a look at [Hadley's tutorial](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Exceptions-Debugging#handling), which has a pretty clear discussion on this.

Comment: This is a good starting point... The IP addresses are in a vector, so I want to run the freegeoip() function, and get a logical vector where TRUE means there was an error and FALSE means I can run freegeoip(). When I use the readLines function I get this error: "invalid 'description' argument". Will edit question with codes I used.

Comment: @camelarms flodel seems to have given you a good answer along the lines of what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
ips <- c('184.26.100.110', '555.22.333.111')

try.ip   <- function(ip) suppressWarnings(try(freegeoip(ip), silent = TRUE))
outcomes <- lapply(ips, try.ip)

is.ok    <- function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error")
sapply(outcomes, is.ok)
# [1] TRUE  FALSE
```

Comment: I tested it this morning with the first 50 elements and it ran very quickly. I've been running outcomes <- lapply(ips,try.ip) for nearly an hour. Should I continue to just wait it out, or am I doing something wrong? @flodel

Comment: Hard to say but 24,867 is a lot of IPs. You could do `system.time(lapply(ips[1:100], try.ip))` and extrapolate how long it should take.

Comment: Finally finished. Ran for 2 hours, and only 686 of those IP addresses were working ;) Thanks again! @flodel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
options(warn=-1)
aaa<-c('123.45.67.89', '999.45.67.89')
bbb<-sapply(aaa, function(x) {a<-freegeoip(x); print(a) })
```

Seems to work for me.