# Modifying a function in R to add ID information?

Tags: r

I've been using this awesome code from the Heuristic Andrew blog and this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536221/).

I want to make a simple modification so that my final output also has the ID information from the original data frame. This is the code that I have right now

```
test1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A123", "A123", "A125", "A126"),
                        IP = c("173.74.6.149", "109.189.227.94",
                               "50.27.115.146", "1.64.170.178")),
                   .Names = c("ID", "IP"), class = "data.frame",
                   row.names = c(NA, 4L))

freegeoip <- function(ip, format = ifelse(length(ip)==1,'list','dataframe'))
{
  if (1 == length(ip))
  {
    # a single IP address
    require(rjson)
    url <- paste(c("http://freegeoip.net/json/", ip), collapse='')
    ret <- fromJSON(readLines(url, warn=FALSE))
    if (format == 'dataframe')
      ret <- data.frame(t(unlist(ret)))
    return(ret)
  } else {
    ret <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:length(ip))
    {
      r <- freegeoip(ip[i], format="dataframe")
      ret <- rbind(ret, r)
    }
    return(ret)
  }
} 

try.ip   <- function(ip) suppressWarnings(try(freegeoip(ip), silent = TRUE))
outcomes <- lapply(test1$IP, try.ip)

is.ok    <- function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error")

outcomes <- outcomes[sapply(outcomes, is.ok)]
outcomes <- do.call("rbind", outcomes)
```

I think the right thing to do would be to modify the `freegeoip` function, but I'm not sure how.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - updated to just add an ID column

add at the end of your code, just looks up the IP, and adds the ID as a new column:

```
outcomes<-data.frame(outcomes)
outcomes$ID<-apply(outcomes,1,FUN=function(x)test1$ID[match(x["ip"],test1$IP)])
```

****************PREVIOUS ANSWER**********************************

The problem if you change the function is that you'll change the shape of data going in and will need to rewrite it quite significantly.

If all you want it to add the results to the outcomes column, why not try `merge()`?

```
idcols<-test1 # make a temp copy of the test1 table
colnames(idcols)<-c("id","ip") # make the ip column header identical to outcomes
merge(idcols,outcomes,by="ip") # merge by ip
```

gives:

```
                  ip   id country_code  country_name region_code region_name    city zipcode latitude  longitude
    1 109.189.227.94 A123           NO        Norway          12        Oslo    Oslo          59.9167     10.75
    2   173.74.6.149 A123           US United States          TX       Texas  Keller   76244  32.9346  -97.2517
    3  50.27.115.146 A125           US United States          TX       Texas Midland          31.9974 -102.0779
    metro_code areacode
    1                    
    2        623      817
    3        633      432
```

Comment: Thanks @Troy. But, what will happen if I have more than one user with the same IP?