# How to store IP address in R and then process it to give IP locations?

Tags: r, rscript, rstudio-server

I was trying to fetch the data I have of some urls and then process it in a form that it returns IP addresses.
I'm receiving an error on storing it.

> hostname_to_ip(i) [[1]] [1] "Not resolved"
>
> Error in strsplit(IP.address, "\.") : non-character argument

```
library(iptools)
library(rvest)
library(Matrix)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(IPtoCountry)

Aircel_ltd <- read_excel("Urls/Aircel ltd.xlsx")

for (i in Aircel_ltd$URL) {
  myIP <- hostname_to_ip(i)
  print(myIP)
  IP_location(myIP)

}
```

Here, Aircel_ltd is the data where Domain names of top five urls are manually saved.

Comment: You can try and load the IPs to a data.frame and do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536221/writing-a-function-to-separate-working-vs-error-values-in-r

Comment: Yes, now I have tried storing it in a dataframe but I'm unable to store it in all different rows. it's taking the same value in all rows. Tell me something about data frame indexing.

Comment: Could you please dput() Aircel_lt or a sample of it? It's a bit difficult to help without knowing how your xlsx file looks like

Comment: I got the solution. Thankyou so much.

Comment: I cleaned my data as hostname can only process domain name not urls.